# What is the difference between Something(Or Verb Dictionary form) + が できます and Something(Or Verb Dictionary form) + ことが できます?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between Something(Or Verb Dictionary form) + が できます and Something(Or Verb Dictionary form) + ことが できます?????

For Example:

> 母は すこし 日本語が できます。
> vs
> 母は すこし 日本語 ことが できます。

Or

> かんじを よむことが できますか。
> vs
> かんじを よむが できますか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Verb Dictionary form + が できます
- Something(=Noun) + ことが できます

are ungrammatical.

So

- 母は すこし 日本語 (Noun) ことが できます。
- かんじを よむ (Verb) が できますか。

are ungrammatical.

The following are the (only) correct forms

- 母は すこし 日本語が できます。
- かんじを よむことが できますか。

Comment: I would suggest you list what IS grammatical, not what isn't... I had to double check what is now really correct, because the logic was reverted

Comment: "Verb Dictionary form + が できます" is actually grammatical, but has different meaning. As you certainly know, besides post-nominal case particle が (subject marker), there is also clause-final particle が, which is translated to English as "but".

Comment: @Arfrever If you mean the が meaning *but*, it is 接続助詞 and not 格助詞 which is relevant here. I'd not think "...が、できます" meaning ".., but it's possible" is an instance of "ができます".

Comment: @sundowner Yes, I meant 接続助詞. できる also has meanings "to be finished, to be ready" and "to be made", and subject can omitted...

Answer (score 0):

In your first example sentence, 「母は すこし 日本語が できます。」日本語 is a noun and the subject of the sentence, so it is marked by が.
In your second example sentence, 「母は すこし 日本語 ことが できます。」because 日本語 is a noun, it cannot attach directly to こと, meaning "thing," which is also a noun. To make one noun modify another, one needs to insert the particle の between them. But there is no need for こと in this example; it would be redundant following the clear meaning of 日本語.
The noun こと can be used following a verb, to turn the verb into a noun-like construction. So you could say, for example, 母は すこし 日本語を読む[よむ] ことが できます。